# Identify pattern in column across time

Tags: sas

Here's my data.

[image]

Each record/row documents the position the patient is in and the document date and time. So, except the first record in a day, we can calculate the time the position has been kept since the last record. The goal is to flag the records that indicate the patient has been in one of the positions: 'right', 'back', 'left', for at least 2 hours in the same day. The red are rows that should be flagged. To do this, I think I need to create a column that has the time at which the last time a different position was documented.

Comment: Please modify your post to include sample data as text. Posting data as an image means someone has to type it out. Instead of the text, please post several cases, some that should be flagged and some should not be flagged.  And include what you expect as output based on the input data. Also include anything you've tried so far, per [ask]. This is relatively straight forward problem to solve once those are clarified.

Answer (score 0):

You are computing the run duration for a `position`.  As your step goes through the data you will need to track the `position` and `start` of a run.  Tracking can be accomplished with a `retain`ed variable.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by patientid date time;  * add date and time to by statement so an error will log if the data is not in the required order;

  if first.patientid then do;
    run_position = position;
    run_start = dhms (date,0,0,0) + time;
    retain run_position run_start;
  end;

  if position = run_position then do;
    hours_duration = intck ('hour', run_start, dhms(date,0,0,0) + time, 'continuous');
  end;
  else do;
    * new run start;
    run_position = position;
    run_start = dhms (date,0,0,0) + time;
    hours_duration = 0;
  end;

  flag_ge2hr = hours_duration >= 2;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `NOTSORTED` option to get this done more easily. Assuming the data is sorted By Date and time correctly, this is what you likely need.

```
data want;
set have; 
by ID position NOTSORTED;
retain start_time;

if first.position then start_time = observation_time;
duration = observation_time - start_time;
if duration > 2*60*60 then flag=1; *time is stored in seconds, so 2 hours * 60minutes * 60 seconds per hour;

run;
```

Untested because no data.